# Bind Entity Framework Class Properties to Temporary Class Properties

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, xsd

I have a database with several tables connected to my program with Entity Framework. Now i have to export this data into a `xml`. The structure of the `xml` i got from a third-party-distributor.
For those purpose i generated some classes with the `xsd.exe` tool.

Now my problem is to parse the generated classes from my `database` to my generated classes from the `XSD`. So i tried to connect the different properties together.
For a better understanding an example with 2 (imaginary and small) classes:

```
              EF-Model          ??how to connect??       XSD-generated
         ___________________                          ____________________
         |table_Customer_DB|                          | XML_Customer     |
         |-----------------|                          |------------------|
DB ----> |ID               | -----------------------> | customerID       | ----> XML
         |Name             | -----------------------> | customerName     |
         |adress           | -----------------------> | customerAdress   |
         ___________________                          ____________________
```

Is it somehow possible to automate such type of connection between different classes and properties or do i have to code this manually?

Comment: This sounds like a job for AutoMapper http://automapper.org/

Comment: not bad...i will test this. Thanks for the hint!